# Cannot create trigger on linked server in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, triggers, linked-server

I have one local database in SQL Server and one Oracle database as an linked server in SQL Server. I want to create a trigger on the linked server (Oracle database table) which will insert data into SQL Server table. This is what I have tried

```
CREATE TRIGGER TrgItemInsert
ON ORACLEDB..SYSTEM.ITEM
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Something Happened to Table ITEM'
END
```

but I get the following error:

> The object name 'ORACLEDB..SYSTEM.ITEM' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.

Is this possible?

Is there any work around to achieve this task?

Connection to the linked server is working and I can query the data in the linked server using 'SELECT' statements.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't. You'd have to write a trigger native to Oracle and create it directly on the oracle server. Triggers are intricately linked into the way that servers process DML statements. The engine running the DML statement has to know about and invoke the trigger(s) at the appropriate times.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever So how can i pass data to the sql server table?